# Transposed convolution on feature maps using Theano

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, theano, convolution, deconvolution

I asked similar question on **[CrossValidation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253724/would-you-interpret-this-image-as-a-correct-deconvolution-process)** for the image interpretation. I'm moving my detailed question here to include some code details.

The results I'm having are not fully desirable So maybe you have faced this issue before and you can help me find it out.

It is fully convolution neural network "no fully connected part".

**Training part**

first the images are transposed to match the convolution function. (batch_no,img_channels,width,height)

```
input.transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)
```

Learning optimized using learning rate:3e-6, Hu_uniform initialization and nestrove for 500 epochs until this convergence.

- Training cost: 1.602449
- Training loss: 4.610442
- validation error: 5.126761
- Test loss: 5.885714

**Backward part**

> Loading Image

```
jpgfile = np.array(Image.open(join(testing_folder,img_name)))
```

> Reshape to one batch

```
batch = jpgfile.reshape(1, jpgfile.shape[0], jpgfile.shape[1], 3)
```

> Run the model to extract first feature map after activation using Relu

```
output = classifier.layer0.output
    Test_model = theano.function(
        inputs=[x],
        outputs=output,
    )

    layer_Fmaps = Test_model(test_set_x)
```

> Apply backwork model to reconstruct the image using the only activated
>   neurons

```
bch, ch, row, col = layer_Fmaps.shape
output_grad_reshaped = layer_Fmaps.reshape((-1, 1, row, col))
output_grad_reshaped = output_grad_reshaped[0].reshape(1,1,row,col)
input_shape = (1, 3, 226, 226)
W = classifier.layer0.W.get_value()[0].reshape(1,3,7,7)
kernel = theano.shared(W)
inp = T.tensor4('inp')
deconv_out = T.nnet.abstract_conv.conv2d_grad_wrt_inputs(
            output_grad = inp,
            filters=kernel,
            input_shape= input_shape,
            filter_shape=(1,3,7,7),
            border_mode=(0,0), 
            subsample=(1,1)
        )
f = theano.function(
            inputs = [inp],
            outputs= deconv_out)

f_out = f(output_grad_reshaped)
deconved_relu =  T.nnet.relu(f_out)[0].transpose(1,2,0)
deconved =  f_out[0].transpose(1,2,0)
```

Here we have two images results, the first is the transposed image without activation and the second with relu since kernels might have some negative weights.

[image: without Relu]
[image: With Relu]

It is clear from the transposed convolution image that this kernel is learn to detect some useful feature related to this image. But the reconstructing part is breaking the image color scheme during the transpose convolution. It might be because the pixels values are small float numbers. Do you see where is the problem here ?